# mysql select most recent, limit by source

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following fields:

- id
- source_id
- title
- date

I want to select the 25 most recent items, so `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 50`

The extra requirement is to select only the 3 most recent from every source_id.

So if the records look something like that,

```
 id | source_id | title |    date
----+-----------+-------+---------
  1       2         aaa   2012-1-1
  2       2         aaa   2012-1-2
  3       2         aaa   2012-1-3
  4       2         aaa   2012-1-4
  5       3         aaa   2012-1-5
  6       4         aaa   2012-1-6
```

I want my query to return items 4,3,2,5,6

So just the 3 most recent of every source with an over all limit of 25.

I'm not sure it's clear enough so please ask if you need more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table t1
WHERE
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM your_table t2
        WHERE
            t1.source_id = t2.source_id
            AND t1.date < t2.date
    ) < 3
ORDER BY source_id, date DESC
```

Result:

```
4   2   aaa 2012-01-04
3   2   aaa 2012-01-03
2   2   aaa 2012-01-02
5   3   aaa 2012-01-05
6   4   aaa 2012-01-06
```

In plain English: take only rows that have less than 3 **newer** rows with the **same `source_id`**.

*NOTE: This could select more than 3 rows per `source_id` if the third newest `date` (for the same `source_id`) happens to be shared by more than one row. Let me know what "3 newest" means in this context if that's a problem...*

Answer (score 0):

```
    select * from table where source_id in 
    (select distinct source_id from table order by date limit 3)
LIMIT 25
```

Comment: It looks as if this selects all the rows from the 3 newest sources. I am looking to select the newest rows limiting it to 3 by source